# Debian Web Server Configuration with 2 Internet Connections

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I have a Debian web server and I'm trying to bind 2 public IP addresses to it.

We have 2 internet connections, the modem for the first is at 192.168.1.1 (we'll call the public ip AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA) and the other is at 192.168.2.1 (BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB).

Can someone help me out with the /etc/network/interfaces file?

Right now I can connect from BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB and from the LAN, but not from AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA

I'd like to use 192.168.1.1 for outgoing connections, either one will work though.

Here is my current /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
allow-hotplug eth0:0
allow-hotplug eth0:1

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.101
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
        address BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB
        netmask 255.255.255.252

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
        address AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA
        netmask 255.255.255.252
#       gateway 192.168.2.1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Edit: Finally got it working. Found this article http://www.debian-administration.org/article/377/Routing_for_multiple_uplinks which helped a lot. I had to also set up a 3rd interface for the local 192.168.2.1/16 network to route the second connection.

Comment: What you are asking is not even remotely trivial to do.  I am not even sure if you can do this.  You are going to have to really complex routing to make this possible.  See this as a starting point.  http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Comment: That seems pretty simple :) Thanks! I'll give this a shot once everyone leaves the office, they're starting to get tired of the website going down ;-)

Comment: Still can't quite figure it out. I changed the other gateway lan ip to another subnet to simplify things (192.168.2.1)